# copy an existing job in jenkins which does 'clean publish'

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, maven-scm

I have a Jenkins job created and working fine where this job connects to a GIT repository and after that the Build task is 'clean publish' . Now I need to create a new job in same Jenkins where this new job connects to other GIT repository and run a build But here this job should not do a 'clean publish' it should perform some other task instead of this.
Can anyone help which task can I perform apart from 'clean publish'. Here I will copy the same existing job which is working fine and I need to modify only the GIT url's and 'tasks' in Build.

Note : this is required since I am working on Migration project where to make sure the new job connects to different GIT repo and perform a build successfully. Only change I require is 'clean publish' instead of clean publish what can I try? Because clean publish will publish to a common archive which is not expected to be done.

Comment: Kindly edit and put some code for understanding the issue you are facing.

Comment: @JafferWilson there is nothing to do with code here, this is just a configuration part in Jenkins job, post executing of build by jenkins job what task can I mention to do instead of 'clean publish' - This is what my question is

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i totally understand your question.  But maybe you are looking for the build matrix plugin which will allow you to run similar jobs with different configs? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understand your question either, but how are you specifying to the job that you intend to do a "clean publish?"

It seems like you are describing ant tasks (or something like it), when you say 'clean publish'.  If that's the case, isn't this just a simple matter of having another job where you are calling different targets?